# How to get the mousdown cursor to apply if cursor is outside of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this fiddle you can grab and drag the black box around a circle

http://jsfiddle.net/S5AT6/

How do I get mousedown cursor(closedhand) to be displayed instead of the default cursor, when the user has grabbed the black box, but their cursor is outside of the `#marker` element and inside the document.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/S5AT6/1/ (I used `help` instead)

Comment: Wow, that jsfiddle is such a mess. You don't need doctype body head etc, it's already provided. Load jquery in the dropdown menu and use the css, html and js boxes, they're there to be used.

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/S5AT6/1/. Now somebody might be able to help. Isn't it so much cleaner? It just took 1 min.

Comment: FTFY. http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/S5AT6/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go: [Solution on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/N8c99/1/)

Things changed:

**CSS**

```
// removed the !important flag here
cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/openhand.cur), default; 

// removed the div#marker here
.mouseDown {
```

**JS**

Added this on doc ready:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', function(event) {
    $('body').removeClass("mouseDown");
});
```

Added this in your mousedown function:

```
$('body').addClass("mouseDown");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the `cursor` style to the entire `<html>`. [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/S5AT6/5/)

Comment: You could also use the css3 grabbing cursor declarations. `cursor: -webkit-grabbing;`, `cursor: -moz-grabbing;`, and `cursor: grabbing;`. More on SitePoint - http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-cursor-styles/#fbid=tXQrrpoxCkt

Comment: @mrtsherman: Thanks, didn't know WebKit supported the grab cursor too.